# install openstack-keystone error：Could not find domain: default

Tags: openstack, keystone

I follow the [official document](https://docs.openstack.org/newton/install-guide-rdo/keystone-verify.html) try to install openstack-keystone

```
 openstack --os-auth-url http://192.168.80.6:35357/v3 \
 --os-project-domain-id default --os-user-domain-id default \
  --os-project-name admin --os-username admin --os-auth-type password \
    token issue
```

Verify that the user can authenticate，error：

```
The request you have made requires authentication. (HTTP 401) (Request-ID: req-8d9e9608-2adb-4b80-bc00-f0fd9e9684ae)
```

I checked log find：

```
2017-10-04 09:06:40.966 1256 INFO keystone.common.wsgi [req-5a17f2ba-ce0e-46cb-8397-707ac9240870 - - - - -] GET http://192.168.80.6:35357/v3/
2017-10-04 09:06:40.982 1243 INFO keystone.common.wsgi [req-8d9e9608-2adb-4b80-bc00-f0fd9e9684ae - - - - -] POST http://192.168.80.6:35357/v3/auth/tokens
2017-10-04 09:06:40.987 1243 WARNING keystone.auth.controllers [req-8d9e9608-2adb-4b80-bc00-f0fd9e9684ae - - - - -] Could not find domain: default
2017-10-04 09:06:40.988 1243 WARNING keystone.common.wsgi [req-8d9e9608-2adb-4b80-bc00-f0fd9e9684ae - - - - -] Authorization failed. The request you have made requires authentication. from 192.168.80.6
```

I checked domain list

```
# openstack domain list 
+---------------------------------+---------+---------+----------------+
| ID                              | Name    | Enabled | Description    |
+---------------------------------+---------+---------+----------------+
| 75391e2f3a1c4c8e94a82d05badb941 | default | True    | Default Domain |
| 8                               |         |         |                |
+---------------------------------+---------+---------+----------------
```

I check  configuration，or unless what I should do ?
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think it has to do with using the project-id instead of project-name. The project name would be default, while the id would be 75391e2f3a1c4c8e94a82d05badb9418.

Change:

```
--os-project-domain-id default
```

to

```
--os-project-name default
```

or

```
--os-project-domain-id 75391e2f3a1c4c8e94a82d05badb9418
```

Update the --os-user-domain-id in the same way.

Give that a try and see if you are able to get a token.